# Update variable in a class after an event (clicking a Tkinter button) in and instance of another class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Below is part of my code. The problem I'm having is I want to insert a value to a Tkinter entry in my main window, but when I call the variable 'selected_db' I get the value of A. I want to get the value after the 'OK button' is clicked so I get the value of B

I'm not sure how should I do it or if this is even close to the right way to do it so I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks in advance

```
Main_Window():

    def browse_db(self):
        my_dbs = Databases()
        self.db_entry.insert(0,my_dbs.selected_db)

    def __init__(self):

        self.main_window = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.db_entry = ttk.Entry(self.main_window, width=10)
        self.db_entry.grid(row=1, column= 1)

Databases():

    def __init__(self):

        self.selected_db = A
        self.db_window = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        okButtom = ttk.Button(self.db_window, command=self.grab_db).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def grab_db(self):
        self.selected_db = B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a complete, working example, but I think what you are asking is how to make your main window wait for your popup to exit. In other words what we usually call a "modal window". To do that you need to pass the master window to the `Toplevel` call and add these commands at the end of the popup's `__init__` method:

```
self.transient(master) # set to be on top of the main window
self.grab_set() # hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
master.wait_window(self) # pause anything on the main window until this one closes
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you! and I'm sorry if the question was not clear enough.